# Dynamic variable name with "this." keyword

Tags: c#

Example:

```
public string varName = "val";
public string val = "some value";

public void meth() 
{
    // Actually need: Trace.WriteLine( this.val);
    Trace.WriteLine( this+ "this.varName"); 
}
```

Actually, I need print `some value`, that is, I need concatenate `this.` keyword with string value, and create something like `dynamic variable`, but not found what is right syntax for this.

Comment: Then just write it like, `this.val`. It is an instance member so there won't be any problem. What error do you get?

Comment: Can you explain what your goal is?

Comment: Sounds like you should have a `Dictionary<string, string>` - or use reflection...

Comment: @ Afzaal  `this.val` works, yes, but I need just understood how to make that, what I asked in question

Comment: Sounds like the OP wants to do string interpolation. Nothing dynamic about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void meth()
{
    var value = GetType().GetField(varName).GetValue(this);
    Trace.WriteLine(value); // "some value"
}
```